# Gumby 2 with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, css-frameworks, gumby-framework

I am trying to integrate the [Gumby frame](http://gumbyframework.com/) work with rails. I have managed to get the CSS working by including the CSS files however I am finding it difficult. Implementing their javascript. Anyone used Gumby with rails successfully ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. It looks like i did not include modernizr in my application. Which is required by gumby. To get it working all i had todo was add the required js files to the assets/javascript path and included them in a specific order as stated [here](http://gumbyframework.com/docs/javascript/#!/installation) in application.js manifest file like so

```
#app/assets/javascript/application.js
//= require modernizr-2.6.2.min.js
//= require gumby.js
//= require gumby.tabs.js
//= require gumby.init.js
```

Comment: Can you post up how you included the CSS as well. Did you use the sass files and have rails compile it, or are you compiling the css manually then including the .css files